# RTMP cannot connect to kick's live stream

Tags: python, rtmp, rtmps

> I'm trying to connect to the **kick.com** *live streaming platform* using **RTMP**, but the problem is that I don't know where to put the **stream key**. I tried both **auth** and **token** but all results in **'Failed to connect'**..

```
import librtmp

stream_key = "sk_us-west-XXXXXXXXXX"

# Create a connection with stream key
con = librtmp.RTMP(
    "rtmps://real1c1b171.global-contribute.live-video.net",
    live=True,
    token=stream_key
)

# librtmp.exceptions.RTMPError: Failed to connect
con.connect()
```